# How show image in asp.net gridview for some values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my project i save some data of "bit" type (true,false) in my mssql database and then show them in a gridview (asp.net - c#) . they showed as check box .
Question :
Can i show a picture in gridview for this Columns **from host (not from database)?** 
example : when value is True pic1.png displayed in column ?!

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: How are you doing data-binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Visible` Property of the Image control you use.

```
<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" 
     ImageUrl="~/Images/myImage.gif" 
     Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "bitColumn") == null ? false: DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "bitColumn") %>' />
```